# Custom entities for Azure Entity Linking Intelligence Service

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is it possible to create your own corpus of entities that are then used through the Azure Entity Linking Intelligence Service?
If yes, then how would one go about creating the dataset.
Thanks